# Not able to connect to AWS IoT Core with cognito authenticated user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I'm trying to follow [this example](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-iot-chat-example/blob/master/docs/authentication.md) but the websocket connection keeps failing.

Here are the steps I have in place (backend implementation using CDK):

1. Cognito User Pool with identity pool and attached authenticated role
2. The auth role gets a AWSIoTDataAccess policy added to it

```
authRole.addManagedPolicy( iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AWSIoTDataAccess'));
```

3. On the front end, I import aws-sdk and aws-iot-device-sdk. Once the user is logged in, I get his credentials with

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
          IdentityPoolId: identityPoolId,
          Logins: { [providerKey]: jwtToken },
        });
```

I now have AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId, AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey, AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken, AWS.config.credentials.identityId available to use

4. In IoT Core, I have created a default policy for testing which I wnat to attach to the cognito identity to be able to connect a mqtt client

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Connect",
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Subscribe",
        "iot:Receive",
        "iot:GetThingShadow",
        "iot:UpdateThingShadow",
        "iot:DeleteThingShadow"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

5. I've tried 2 ways to attache this policy (and I suspect this is the problem, as I don't know how to check if the cognito identity has received it)

- option 1: api call to Lambda in the backend, passing in AWS.config.credentials.identityId

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
const iot = new aws.Iot();
exports.handler = async function(event:any) {

 let data = JSON.parse(event.body)
 await iot.attachPolicy({ policyName: 'default', principal: data.identityId })
 return sendRes(201, {message: 'policy attached'});
}
```

- option 2: try to load the aws-sdk on the front-end and attach with

```
 iot.attachPolicy({ policyName: 'default', principal: AWS.config.credentials.identityId })
```

6. With all this in place, I create a device from `import AWSIoTData from 'aws-iot-device-sdk'`

```
var mqttClient = AWSIoTData.device({
          region: 'eu-central-1,
          host: 'xxx-my-iot-core-endpoint',
          clientId: 'testxxx-' + (Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1)),
          protocol: 'wss',
          maximumReconnectTimeMs: 8000,
          debug: false,
        //  port: 443, //I had this on and off to no effect
          accessKeyId:'' ,
          secretKey: '',
          sessionToken: ''
        })

        mqttClient.updateWebSocketCredentials(
          AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId, 
          AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey, 
          AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken
        );

        mqttClient.on('connect', function () {
          console.log('mqttClient connected')
          mqttClient.subscribe(currentlySubscribedTopic)
        })
```

This whole process never gets to the connect step, as the websocket connection fails.
In the console, I can see
`wss://xxxxxxxxxxx-ats.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mqtt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=undefined%2F20210427%2Feu-central-1%2Fiotdevicegateway%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210427T135809Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=...`

So I assume I also need the request to be using 'aws-signature-v4'. This is where I'm stuck.

I also followed another example where it was suggested to have a Lambda function to get a presigned Url like this:

```
const url = v4.createPresignedURL(
          'GET', endpoint + ":443",'/mqtt', 'iotdevicegateway',
          crypto.createHash('sha256').update('', 'utf8').digest('hex'),
          {
              key: data.accessKeyId,
              secret: data.secretAccessKey,
              sessionToken: data.SessionToken,
              protocol: 'wss',
              region: 'eu-central-1',
          }
        );
```

I've managed to get the url and tried to use it with the Paho client `import Paho from 'paho-mqtt'`
and then  `var mqttClient = new Paho.Client(presignedurl, clientId);`

none of this brought a result, so I'm grateful for any advice.